# C++: Linked List Representation

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

The way **I** know how to represent a linked list is basically creating a **Node** class (more preferably a **struct**), and the creating the actual **linkedList** class. However, yesterday I was searching for the logic of **reversing a singly linked list** operation and almost 90% of the solutions I've encountered was including that the function, returning data type **Node*** . Thus I got confused since if you want to reverse a list no matter what operation you done, wouldn't it be in the type of **linkedList** again? Am I doing it the wrong way?

The linked list implementation **I** do all the time;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

class linkedList
{
public:
    Node* firstPtr;
    Node* lastPtr;

    linkedList()
    {
        firstPtr=lastPtr=NULL;
    }
    void insert(int value)
    {
        Node* newNode=new Node;
        newNode->data=value;
        if(firstPtr==NULL)
            firstPtr=lastPtr=newNode;
        else {
            newNode->next=firstPtr;
            firstPtr=newNode;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        Node *temp=firstPtr;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<" ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide the function call for list reversal which you find confusing?

Comment: The focus of the question is not actually the **reversal** function but why functions **(like reversal)** would return the value type **Node**

Comment: @rolandbishop: In your example, `LinkedList` is just a wrapper to hide the implementation details (`Node*`) from the client, while the solutions you saw one the net only focused on the implementation to be terse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You approach isn't wrong, but you might be giving too much emphasis on your `linkedList` class.

What does that class actually contain? A pointer to the first node, and a pointer to the last node (which is redundant information, since you can find the last node by only knowing the first one). So basically `linkedList` is just a helper class with no extra information.

The member functions from `linkedList` could easily be moved inside `Node` or made free functions that take a `Node` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! So we create the linked list, reverse it in memory and just point to its initial node then?

Comment: @rolandbishop well... you point to the new first node. Which probably isn't your initial node, if you reversed the list.

Comment: I guess the "well.." part caused by me not being able to express myself quickly. I've perfectly understood what you meant but thing I ask is that can we simply call that **a linked list** is basically can be obtained by a single node which is pointing to its initial node, right?

Comment: @rolandbishop right. A linked list is a pointer to the first node.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what is a linked list but a pointer to the first node? A list is fully accessible provided you can get to the first node, and all you need for that is a pointer to the first node.

Unless you want to store *extra* control information about the list (such as its length for example), there's no need for a separate data type for the list itself.

Now some implementations (such as yours) may also store a pointer to the last node in the list for efficiency, allowing you to append an item in O(1) instead of O(n). But that's an *extra* feature for the list, not a *requirement* of lists in general.

Comment: Thanks makes great sense. So we just need a pointer to **point** the list arranged in the memory right?

Comment: @rolandbishop: I assume you meant "... to point **to** the list ..." in which case you're right. That's all you _need._ It's not necessarily all you _want_ since, as stated, your extra control information has some advantages. So does storing the length since it makes `size()` O(1) rather than O(n) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions might be returning of type Node* because after reversing the linked-list they will return the pointer to the First node of the list.